# how to add constraint to check values in table column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table etblshopaccount to that i want to add constraint so that while exporting the data from excel to sql server native client the column shopaccountcity should be added with cityname 'texas' if there is no value in the excel data.i.e.,

shopaccountcity is not  null column and i want to add texas by default to the column if the field has no value in the excel.

i came up with this query is successful but there is no result

```
alter table EtblShopAccount add default (isnull(null,'Texas')) for [ShopAccountCity]
```

Comment: I want to use check constraint that will check the null value and if it is present then i want to set that value to texas can anyone write this query language

Answer (score 1):

Modify to this:

```
ALTER TABLE EtblShopAccount 
ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName DEFAULT N'Texas' FOR [ShopAccountCity];
```

Comment: No yar not working if the value in the excel column is null then import is failed and didnot write any rows.so i think it needs to check the value is null then it should add texas otherwise the one which is there in excel should be imported to sql server..any more ideas

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE EtblShopAccount 
 add constraint df_ShopAccountCity 
 default 'Texas' for [ShopAccountCity]
```

i.e., instead of using the function `isnull()` you can better add it as a constraint. So it means whenever you are not going to provide the value for your `ShopAccountCity` column it will take the default value as `Texas`

Also you can use the UPDATE script if you want to update the NULL values to 'Texas' before doing running the wizard

```
update EtblShopAccount 
set ShopAccountCity = 'Texas'
where ShopAccountCity is NULL
```

Comment: u are saying to add the column but the column is already there and moreover i want to import the data from excel through import and export wizard so i want to run the constraint before importing  EtblShopAccount  table so that constraint will chk the column  ShopAccountCity  then if there is null value in the column then it should be given the value texas, why i need this is as it is not null field if the field is null in excel then importing fails .

Comment: @GSM:- I just updated my answer. I thought you are adding the column as well. But since you are adding the constraint only then the above query should work.

Comment: @RahulTripathi what if excell cell is empty string then u need maybe another constraint